# JavaScript not executed on clicking button in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I am new to web programming and currently working on Django.

I have a html page with 3 buttons

```
            <p style = "color:black;"> <b> Your options: </b></p>
            <p style="padding-bottom: 40px;"><button>A</button></p>
            <p style="padding-bottom: 40px;"><button>B</button></p>
            <p style="padding-bottom: 40px;"><button>C</button></p>
```

The script that needs to be executed after clicking on any one of this is as follows:

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('submit_button').onclick = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#submit_form').css('display', 'none');
            $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());
                },
                url: window.location.pathname,
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function () {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
            return false;
        };
    </script>
```

However, when I click on any one of the buttons, nothing happens.

Comment: None of your buttons have that id.  And ids shouldn't repeat.  So give those buttons a shared class, and select by that class, loop over them, and put the binding on them

Comment: Which, you are using jquery, so intermixing a native selector with jquery selectors like that is already a code smell.  If you are already taking the hit for loading jquery on the page, use it.

Answer (score 1):

None of your buttons have id `submit_button`. Which you have stated in the event handler:

```js
document.getElementById('submit_button').onclick {
```

You need to add it to one of them like so:

```html
<p style="padding-bottom: 40px;"><button id="submit_button">A</button></p>
```